# Minimum letter constraint in regex pattern along with special characters

Tags: regex

Currently, I am not expert in Regex, but I tried below thing I want to improve it better, can some one please help me?

Pattern can contain ASCII letters, spaces, commas, periods, `'`, `.` and `-` special characters, and there can be one digit at the end of string.

So, it's working well
`/^[a-z ,.'-]+(\d{1})?$/i`

But I want to put condition that **at least 2 letters** should be there, could you please tell me, how to achieve this and explain me bit as well, please?

Comment: You mean *letter*, not *character*, right? Like `/^(?:[ ,.'-]*[a-z]){2,}[ ,.'-]*\d?$/i`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thanks a lot and yes you are right, suppose, In case If I want to have letters at the beginning always , how should I modify the answer you pinged, can you please help me?

Comment: Then, `/^(?:[a-z][ ,.'-]*){2,}\d?$/i`, even shorter.

Comment: Thank you very much @WiktorStribiżew, I have understood it pretty well now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `{1}` is always redundant in any regex, please remove it to make the regex pattern more readable. `(\d{1})?` is equal to `\d?` and matches an optional digit.

Taking into account the string must start with a letter, you can use

```
/^(?:[a-z][ ,.'-]*){2,}\d?$/i
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group (it is used here as a container for a pattern sequence to quantify):

  - `[a-z]` - an ASCII letter
  - `[ ,.'-]*` - zero or more spaces, commas, dots, single quotation marks or hyphens
- `){2,}` - end of group, repeat two or more (`{2,}`) times
- `\d?` - an optional digit
- `$` - end of string
- `i` - case insensitive matching is ON.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1OEmjI/1).

Answer (score 1):

The thing to change in your regex is `+` after the list of allowed characters.

`+` means one or many occurrences of the provided characters. If you want to have 2 or more you can use `{2,}`

So your regex should look something like

```regex
/^[a-z ,.'-]{2,}\d?$/i
```